# How to send custom emails in Django Admin?

Tags: python, django, email

I need to send custom emails to users after verifying their applications are correct in django admin.The emails are to be sent to a single user and each message will be different depending on the application of the user.I needed to ask whether this is possible in django admin and if so, how can I do it without hardcoding the message each time I want to send the email?

Comment: I flagged this for closure as it is too broad.  This is a great site to find answers to coding problems but you need to start the process by showing some code and explaining why you are having a problem.  There are a number of ways to evaluate a users application and generate a text stream based on the evaluation and then generate an email based on the text stream.  So start solving your problem one step at a time, for example the verification of their application.  Once you hit a snag come back

Comment: PyNEwbie Thanks for the response.I have done emails after application submission and is working okay.My issue up here is due to the fact that , a staff checks the application and communicates back to the client.Hope you get my point

Answer (score 0):

You can use [django signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/signals/) there you should check that applivation was verified and send email to user. Content for email you can generate from template by [rendering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.base.Template.render) it to string and send it as email's body. Content will be depend on context which you put to `render`

Comment: @Moiseenko I have used signals before and they are okay.I have tried the rendering of templates as you suggest above but cannot really figure it out.Will I get something like a textarea to input the message body when sending the email?

Comment: @Wanjohi254 Yes you can add model with textarea and fetch data from it. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-mail-dbtpl/0.2.2 there is example how you can implement it

Comment: @Moiseenko Thanks for the answer provided earlier.I have been working on the solution you suggested and looks a good idea.I added as an action in django admin and created the templates and its sending the email.The issue is that it sends the mail in the template i.e. The text or html writtedn in template. You mentioned something about model and fetching data from it.Could you please elaborate on that and maybe how I can go through it.